# Running a boost thread as a Daemon

Tags: c++, daemon, boost-thread

Is it possible to create a boost::thread and run it in the background (as a daemon)?
I am trying to the following but my thread dies when main exits.

```
/*
 * Create a simple function which writes to the console as a background thread.
 */
void countDown(int counter) {
    do {
        cout << "[" << counter << "]" << endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep(seconds(1));
    }while(counter-- > 0);
}

int main() {
    boost::thread t(&countDown, 10);

    if(t.joinable()) {
        cout << "Detaching thread" << endl;
        t.detach(); //detach it so it runs even after main exits.
    }

    cout << "Main thread sleeping for a while" << endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(seconds(2));
    cout << "Exiting main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[rajat@localhost threads]$ ./a.out

Detaching thread

Main thread sleeping for a while

[10]

[9]

Exiting main

[rajat@localhost threads]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `main()` exits all other threads of the process are terminated (assuming Linux, can't say for Windows).

Why not just `join()` that background thread at the end of the `main()`? Or even better - use the main thread as the "daemon" thread?

Comment: Thanks, but what's the purpose of the thread.detach() then? I thought it was there to allow threads to run even after main thread exits. Is there a way that I can run say 10 threads in the background without joining them..? If I join them, then I'll need to run my application in the background using nohup.

Comment: Detaching a thread is to indicate that the resources for the thread can be released and as mentioned [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.detach), thread ceases to exist after detachment.

Comment: @Rajat, read up on how Linux processes and threads work, you have some skewed assumptions here.